# How to change field data type master detail relationship to lookup relationship field in salesforce

Tags: object, salesforce, admin, lookup, master-detail

I want to change field data type master detail relationship to lookup relationship. but i'm not getting change data type button on that field. my instance is enterprise edition

i have try to edit field but did't work

Comment: do you have any rollup update fields? you may have to remove them first. what if you export the project with sfdx/vscode, manually change in the xml and try deploying that?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to be sure that the field you are trying to edit is no standard. Standard fields cannot be edited.